# Leaftlet: How to dynamically filter a GeoJSON dataset in to a series of Layer checkboxes?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a web page which fetches some marker pin locations from a local database and also a collection of features from a remote GeoJSON source (API).

Currently, there are two check boxes available to the user to allow them to choose which of the two layers they want to view.  This all works fine:

```
<script>

    // Center the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([54.233669, -4.406027], 6);


    // Attribution
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=REMOVED', {
        attribution: 'Map &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);



    // Create an empty layergroup for the Locations data
    var LayerLocations = L.layerGroup();

    // Format the popup markers for the Locations
    function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        // Image
        var ImageContent
        if (feature.properties.ImageURL) {
            ImageContent = "<img src='" + feature.properties.ImageURL + "' width='300' height='200' /><br /><br />"
        } else if (feature.properties.YouTubeID) {
                ImageContent = "<img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + feature.properties.YouTubeID + "/hqdefault.jpg' width='300' height='200' /><br /><br />"

        } else {
            ImageContent = ""
        }

        // Build the popup content
        var popupContent = "<h4>" +
            feature.properties.Title +
            Author +
            "</h4>" +
            ImageContent +
            CommentsContent +
            "View and discuss this location.";
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }

    // Build layer: Locations
    fetch("JSONMapPoints.json")
      .then(function (response) { return response.json() })
      .then(function (data) {
          // Create a L.GeoJSON out of the data
          var locations = L.geoJson(data, {
              onEachFeature: forEachFeature,
              pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                  return L.marker(latlng, {
                      icon: L.icon({
                      iconUrl: "images/pins/" + feature.properties.CategoryID + ".png",
                      iconSize: [32, 37],
                      iconAnchor: [10, 32],
                      popupAnchor: [5, -30]
                      }),
                  })
              }
          });
          // Add the L.GeoJSON instance to the empty layergroup
          map.fitBounds(locations.getBounds());
          LayerLocations.addLayer(locations).addTo(map);
    });


    // Create an empty layergroup for the Guardian UTM data
    var LayerGuardianUTM = L.layerGroup();

    // Style the Guardian UTM features
    function setStyle(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor,
            color: feature.properties.strokeColor,
            fillOpacity: feature.properties.fillOpacity,
            opacity: feature.properties.strokeOpacity
        };
    }

    // Build Layer: Guardian UTM
    function getGuardianUTMdata() {
        LayerGuardianUTM.clearLayers();
        fetch("https://example.com/v2/mapdata/geojson?n=" + map.getBounds().getNorth() + "&e=" + map.getBounds().getEast() + "&s=" + map.getBounds().getSouth() + "&w=" + map.getBounds().getWest(), { headers: { 'Authorization': 'REMOVED', 'X-AA-DeviceId': 'mySite' } })
          .then(function (responseGuardianUTM) { return responseGuardianUTM.json() })
          .then(function (dataGuardianUTM) {
              // Create a L.GeoJSON out of the data
              var featuresAA = L.geoJson(dataGuardianUTM, {
                  style: setStyle,
                  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                      return L.marker(latlng, { icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: feature.properties.iconUrl }), })
                  },
                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                  },
              });
              // Add the L.GeoJSON instance to the empty layergroup
              LayerGuardianUTM.addLayer(featuresAA).addTo(map);
          });
    }


    // Update the Guardian UTM layer if the map moves
    map.on('dragend', function () { getGuardianUTMdata(); });
    map.on('zoomend', function () { getGuardianUTMdata(); });


    // Layer controls
    var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
        'Locations': LayerLocations,
        'Restrictions & Hazards': LayerGuardianUTM
    }).addTo(map);


</script>
```

I wish to increase the functionality available to the end user.

Instead of a single checkbox to turn on/off the `Restrictions & Hazards` layer, I wish to iterate through the GeoJSON returned from the API and dynamically build a series of checkboxes under the Layer button/icon based on the `feature.properties.filters.name`.

So when the user clicks on the Layers button icon they should see a series of checkboxes which would allow them to pick and choose which of the features in the GeoJSON they wish to view.

The GeoJSON returned from the API is dynamic and its content changes based on the users location and zoom level.

An example of the GeoJSON is:

```
{
    "isCompleteData": true,
    "excludedData": [],
    "countriesInViewport": [],
    "nationalFlightRestrictions": [],
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        -2.6300508975982666,
                        53.536331176757812
                    ],
                    [
                        -2.6293964385986328,
                        53.533683776855469
                    ],
                    [
                        -2.6288816928863525,
                        53.531524658203125
                    ],
                    [
                        -2.6228303909301758,
                        53.529739379882813
                    ],
                    [
                        -2.6218380928039551,
                        53.528053283691406
                    ],
                    [
                        -2.6206841468811035,
                        53.526073455810547
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
            },
            "id": "A05B59534A594F20583A3B8EB479F211E507F265",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "40",
                "hazardFactorName": "Warning",
                "fillColor": "#ffbb00",
                "strokeColor": "#b88702",
                "fillOpacity": "0.35",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "power:line",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=power_line.png",
                "name": "Power Line",
                "category": "groundHazard",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Ground Hazards",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "Ground Hazard",
                    "detailedCategory": "Power Line",
                    "title": "Ground Hazard",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=power_line.png",
                            "title": "Power Hazard",
                            "text": "The highlighted area is believed to contain power infrastructure. Power infrastructure presents heightened risk of damage to your equipment and critical National infrastructure."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Yellow zones indicate regions where operation of your drone may raise security, privacy or safety concerns."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.6228303909301758,
                    53.529739379882813
                ],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "id": "6EB24E66D75083A4A135296C12BE004D79629818",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "40",
                "hazardFactorName": "Warning",
                "fillColor": "#ffbb00",
                "strokeColor": "#b88702",
                "fillOpacity": "0.35",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "power:tower",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=power_tower.png",
                "name": "Power Pylon",
                "category": "groundHazard",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Ground Hazards",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "Ground Hazard",
                    "detailedCategory": "Power Pylon",
                    "title": "Ground Hazard",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=power_tower.png",
                            "title": "Power Hazard",
                            "text": "The highlighted area is believed to contain power infrastructure. Power infrastructure presents heightened risk of damage to your equipment and critical National infrastructure."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Yellow zones indicate regions where operation may raise security, privacy or safety concerns."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -2.6234986782073975,
                            53.533077239990234
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.6215133666992187,
                            53.528900146484375
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.6183879375457764,
                            53.529270172119141
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.6178712844848633,
                            53.529655456542969
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "id": "557952B3668AC5DF5C583BE8E8C1840D97B5ABD4",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "40",
                "hazardFactorName": "Warning",
                "fillColor": "#ffbb00",
                "strokeColor": "#b88702",
                "fillOpacity": "0.35",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "landuse:cemetery",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=landuse_cemetery.png",
                "name": "Wigan Borough Cemetery",
                "category": "groundHazard",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Ground Hazards",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "Ground Hazard",
                    "detailedCategory": "Cemetery",
                    "title": "Wigan Borough Cemetery",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Yellow zones indicate regions where operation of your drone may raise security, privacy or safety concerns."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -3.235,
                            53.53694
                        ],
                        [
                            -3.05278,
                            53.45944
                        ],
                        [
                            -3.20139,
                            53.38583
                        ],
                        [
                            -3.02778,
                            53.24083
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.73028,
                            53.10722
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "id": "616CB45B9DA924146E9A5483843B588B36F0AD31",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "60",
                "hazardFactorName": "Danger",
                "fillColor": "#ffffff",
                "strokeColor": "#ffffff",
                "fillOpacity": "0.2",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "type:tma",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=class_type_tma.png",
                "airac": {
                    "to": "2019-08-15",
                    "from": "2019-07-18"
                },
                "altitudeFloor": {
                    "datum": "Msl",
                    "meters": 1066.7999983784639,
                    "feet": 3499.9999946799994
                },
                "altitudeCeiling": {
                    "datum": "Sps",
                    "meters": 7467.5999886492482,
                    "feet": 24499.99996276
                },
                "name": "MANCHESTER TMA 1",
                "listOrderHint": "1000",
                "category": "airspace",
                "designator": "EGCC1",
                "airspaceType": "TMA",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Upper Airspace",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": false
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Type TMA",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "airspace",
                    "detailedCategory": "Type TMA",
                    "title": "MANCHESTER TMA 1",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Altitude",
                            "text": "This piece of airspace is in effect above 1067m / 3500ft MSL"
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Terminal control area",
                            "text": "Control area normally established at the confluence of ATS routes in the vicinity of one or more major aerodromes."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Regulated Airspace",
                            "text": "This airspace has a specific classification."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Red zones are regulated high-risk areas."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -3.05278,
                            53.45944
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.06667,
                            53.575
                        ],
                        [
                            -2.83333,
                            53.53333
                        ],
                        [
                            -3.05278,
                            53.45944
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "id": "BC69E04789D9A790DB5B29B0EE2804D42E4FA12A",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "60",
                "hazardFactorName": "Danger",
                "fillColor": "#ffffff",
                "strokeColor": "#ffffff",
                "fillOpacity": "0.2",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "class:d",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=class_d.png",
                "airac": {
                    "to": "2019-08-15",
                    "from": "2019-07-18"
                },
                "altitudeFloor": {
                    "datum": "Msl",
                    "meters": 761.99999884176,
                    "feet": 2499.9999961999997
                },
                "altitudeCeiling": {
                    "datum": "Msl",
                    "meters": 1066.7999983784639,
                    "feet": 3499.9999946799994
                },
                "name": "MANCHESTER CTA 1",
                "listOrderHint": "600",
                "category": "airspace",
                "designator": "EGCC1",
                "airspaceClass": "D",
                "airspaceType": "CTA",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Upper Airspace",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": false
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Class  D",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "airspace",
                    "detailedCategory": "Class  D",
                    "title": "MANCHESTER CTA 1",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Altitude",
                            "text": "This piece of airspace is in effect above 762m / 2500ft MSL"
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Regulated Airspace",
                            "text": "This airspace has a specific classification."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Red zones are regulated high-risk areas."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -10,
                            54.56667
                        ],
                        [
                            -9,
                            54.75
                        ],
                        [
                            -8.25,
                            55.33333
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "id": "11DD2D3CBA8992F29E49A277FC322D19FCD67066",
            "properties": {
                "hazardFactor": "60",
                "hazardFactorName": "Danger",
                "fillColor": "#ffffff",
                "strokeColor": "#ffffff",
                "fillOpacity": "0.2",
                "strokeWidth": "1",
                "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
                "detailedCategory": "type:cta",
                "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=class_type_cta.png",
                "airac": {
                    "to": "2019-08-15",
                    "from": "2019-07-18"
                },
                "altitudeFloor": {
                    "datum": "Sps",
                    "meters": 7467.5999886492482,
                    "feet": 24499.99996276
                },
                "altitudeCeiling": {
                    "datum": "Sps",
                    "meters": 20116.799969422464,
                    "feet": 65999.99989968
                },
                "name": "UPPER AIRSPACE CTA",
                "listOrderHint": "1000",
                "category": "airspace",
                "designator": "EGUP",
                "airspaceType": "CTA",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "Upper Airspace",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": false
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Type CTA",
                        "property": "show",
                        "active": true
                    }
                ],
                "display": {
                    "category": "airspace",
                    "detailedCategory": "Type CTA",
                    "title": "UPPER AIRSPACE CTA",
                    "sections": [
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Altitude",
                            "text": "This piece of airspace is in effect above FL244.9999996276"
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Control area",
                            "text": "A controlled airspace extending upwards from a specified limit above the earth."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Regulated Airspace",
                            "text": "This airspace has a specific classification."
                        },
                        {
                            "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.example.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
                            "title": "Summary",
                            "text": "Red zones are regulated high-risk areas."
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": []
                }
            },
            "type": "Feature"
        }
    ],
    "bbox": [
        -2.6261,
        53.5288,
        -2.6201,
        53.5308
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

Based on the example GeoJSON the Layers button should contain checkboxes for:

- `Locations`
- `Ground Hazards`
- `Upper Airspace`

Is this even possible?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create more than one `L.GeoJSON` instance, and leverage their [`filter` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson-filter):

> A `Function` that will be used to decide whether to include a feature or not. The default is to include all features:
>
> ```
> function (geoJsonFeature) {
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> Note: dynamically changing the filter option will have effect only on newly added data. It will not re-evaluate already included features.

e.g.:

```
fetch("JSONMapPoints.json")
  .then(function (response) { return response.json() })
  .then(function (data) {
      
      var locations = L.geoJson(data, {
          filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.filters.name === 'Location'},
          /* etc */
      });
      var hazards = L.geoJson(data, {
          filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.filters.name === 'Hazard'},
          /* etc */
      });
      var airspace = L.geoJson(data, {
          filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.filters.name === 'Air Space'},
          /* etc */
      });
});
```

With those different `L.GeoJSON` instances, adding them to a layers control is just a matter of calling [`addOverlay()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#control-layers-addoverlay), e.g.

```
layersControl.addOverlay(locations, "Locations");      
layersControl.addOverlay(hazards, "Hazards);    
layersControl.addOverlay(airspace, "Air Space");
```

Beware of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), though. A newbie JS mistake is to *assume* that a variable will magically exist in the scope where it's needed. In this particular case, I would ensure that the layers control is already instantiated when the GeoJSON layers are created, and add them to said layers control.

---

A more convoluted approach would be to automatically detect the categories or filters, iterating through the GeoJSON structure to get them, e.g.:

```
fetch("JSONMapPoints.json")
  .then(function (response) { return response.json() })
  .then(function (data) {
     
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
    var categories = new Set();

    for (var i in data) {
      var feature = data[i];
      categories.add(feature.properties.filters.name);
    }
```

Then iterate through the categories to programmatically create the `L.GeoJSON` instances, paying attention to the appropriate closures:

```
    categories.forEach(function(category) {
      var layer = L.geoJSON(data, {
        filter: function(f){ f.properties.filters.name === category }
        /* etc */ });
      layersControl.addOverlay(layer, category);
    });

// And we're done here.
});
```

This is a bit over-engineered for a dataset needing three filters, but would work nicely when there's a larger amount.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez. I tried your first approach.  Alas, it does not work, but I do not get any errors in the console either.  Is the filter correct? Am I using .addTo(map) correctly? I can't see what else may be wrong https://pastebin.com/FKyZNscx

Comment: I don't see anything wrong right now. I'm not seeing where you're creating the layergroups and adding those to the map, though; better to publish complete examples. Try adding a `debugger` statement inside the `filter` function to check for dumb typos (e.g. `Ground Hazards` vs `Ground hazard` or the like).